# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, runtime-error

I am trying to build a spring boot application but it's giving the above errors, already tried the web, but I  can't understand the problem. Please help me to solve it.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.manav.location</groupId>
<artifactId>locationWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>locationWeb</name>
<description>Location Module</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>9.0.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

stacktrace:

```
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:31.560[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.manav.location.LocationWebApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting LocationWebApplication using Java 15.0.2 on SSDN with PID 6020 (C:\Users\manav\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE\locationWeb\target\classes started by manav in C:\Users\manav\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE\locationWeb)
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:31.565[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.manav.location.LocationWebApplication [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:33.898[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:34.046[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 123 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:35.345[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:35.363[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:35.364[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
[2m2021-04-04 15:14:35.562[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m6020[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Do you have more information in your logs? The ones in your question end just before the real error should appear.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: The log files or console output must contain a complete stack trace, which will explain **why** the context didn't start. The part you included in the question contains the exception, but not its cause.